# VK API | Некорректная работа метода messages.getByConversationMessageId?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Доброго времени суток!

Разрабатываю бота для сообщества при помощи PHP и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Нужно пересылать сообщения пользователей, но в callback-логе `id` сообщения всегда равно 0, присутствует только `conversation_message_id`.

Была идея при помощи метода `getByConversationMessageId` получать информацию о сообщении, а оттуда доставать id, НО, при попытке отправить запрос с ключом сообщества, либо указанным `group_id` - в ответ получаю лишь

```
{
   "response": {
     "count": 0,
     "items": []
   }
}
```

В чём может быть ошибка или есть ли какие-то другие способы получить `id` сообщения для последующей пересылки?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Не знаю как написать тс в лс, если есть решение данной проблемы был бы благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В личных сообщениях id сообщения передаётся корректно, однако в беседах на данный момент не передаётся.